# Azure AD B2C Custom Domain

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

There does not seem to be an option to set up a custom domain for Azure AD B2C. With Azure AD it was available. The B2C version has a side help panel which indicates custom domains can be used, but no indication on how to do it.
[image]

Does anyone know how that can be done? (I'm specifically referring to the B2C version of AD.)

**UPDATE**
Here is a screenshot of where I am in the portal. This is just after I clicked the link "The domain name I need isn't shown here"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you shared seems to be a description of Azure AD only (not Azure AD B2C).

Currently this feature is on the roadmap. Verifying your domain in the **Domains** tab in the Azure portal does not accomplish your goal.

See details from [Azure AD B2C: FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs#can-i-use-my-own-urls-on-my-sign-up-and-sign-in-pages-that-are-served-by-azure-ad-b2c-for-instance-can-i-change-the-url-from-contosob2clogincom-to-logincontosocom).

Comment: The screenshot came from the page for B2C.

Comment: And I don't think there is a Domains tab at all in B2C (there is a Custom Domains tab in the normal AD)

Comment: Please share the article for B2C here. And yes, Domains tab means the Custom Domains tab in the normal AD. So it does not accomplish your goal as it mentioned.

Comment: The screenshot is not from an article--it is from the user management menu blade for AD B2C in in the Azure portal.

Comment: Can you include the breadcrumbs UI from the top left of your portal page to show where in the portal you see this UI (e.g. Home
XYZ - Overview)? I suspect you are using the AAD blade while the portal has your B2C tenant as default. Most of the functionality of the AAD blade is not applicable to B2C.

Comment: Hi @DonnyKwitty, as  Marc suggested, could you share a full screenshot to show the location of what you are seeing in Azure portal?

Comment: Marc & Allen, I've added a screen shot. Thanks!

Comment: Although what you see is in Azure AD B2C, you will actually see the exact same content when you visit Azure Active Directory > Users - All Users > +New user. So this does not mean that the custom domain you see is under Azure AD B2C. You can click on the link it provided, and then you will be redirected to the documentation of Azure AD instead of Azure AD B2C.